# Passing markup from Child to parent in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there any example on how can we pass markup/slots from child to parent?

Comment: Here is the link to slots documentation in LWC - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_slots

What are you trying to achieve? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass markup from a child to its parent, only from a parent to its child. Whatever you're attempting to do isn't supported by LWC or Web Components in general.

Comment: Sure, Thank you!